Detect the end of the matplotlib resize event
How do I detect the end of a resize event in matplotlib?
The resize event does not fire when the mouse button is released, and the release event does not fire either.
Is there no way?

Why is does matplotlib's inbuilt ResizeEvent not work for you?
